# `software-center` couldn't start in ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, gnome, software-center

After  a fresh install of ubuntu 14.04LTS, i get the following error message, while running `software-center` on `terminal`:[image]
What is the problem here? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Similar issue has been reported in Ubuntu launchpad and fixed. As per the statement it is due to one of the python imports. Please check the link below for further details

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/438366

Comment: Do I have to download the file stating `fix released` and install or what?

Comment: That bug  is very old and has been fixed according to the devs. I think this is a different one or maybe that has reborn.

Comment: So if I report this bug, and if the fix is released after some days what i should do?